# Why curve fit function does not combine all data points. How to get best fit?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy

I'm not familiar that how to decide the fitting function? But by looking at the trend of data points I choosed Poisson distribution as my fitting function. Green curve is quite smooth but fitting curve is is far away from first data point having position (0,0.55). I want to get smooth curve using fitting function because it is far away from my actual data points. I tried to increase number of bins but still getting same type of curve. I have doubt that may be I am not choosing proper fitting function or may be I am missing something else?

```
`def Poisson_fit(x,a):
    return (a*np.exp(-x))
def Poisson(x):
    return (np.exp(-x))
x_data =np.linspace(0,5,10)
print("x_data: ",x_data)
[0.,0.55555556, 1.11111111, 1.66666667, 2.22222222, 2.77777778, 3.33333333, 
3.88888889, 4.44444444, 5.]

hist, bin_edges= np.histogram(x, bins=10, density=True)
print("hist: ",hist)
#hist:[5.41041394e-01,1.42611032e-01,3.44975130e-02,7.60221121e-03,
 1.66115522e-03,3.26808028e-04,6.70741368e-05,1.14168743e-05,5.70843717e-06, 
1.42710929e-06]
plt.scatter(x_data, hist,marker='o',color='red')

popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(Poisson_fit, x_data, hist)
plt.plot(x_data, Poisson_fit(x_data,*popt), linestyle='--', 
marker='.',color='red', label='Fit')

plt.plot(x_data,Poisson(x_data),marker='.',color='green',label='Poisson')`
```

[image]

```
#Second Graph(Find best fit)
```

In the following graph I have fit two different distributions on data points. For me its hard to judge which is best fit. Should I print error on the fitting function to judge the best fit?

```
`perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt the image is produced by the code shown. When I run the code the outpu is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69mmr.png), where the curve is in the middle between the first and all other points. That makes total sense for a fit like this.

Comment: Then may be I forgot to replace the fitting function. But in the second plot how I can fit 2  or 3 different distributions on my data points. So how to decide best fit in that case?

Comment: A fit is used to find out how well the data is descibed by a model or to find the free parameters in a model. Here it seems neither model is well suited to describe the data. A side note: mind that you probably shouldn't use the bin *edges* for fitting, but rather the centers.

Comment: Actually I'm not using bin-edges. I'm simply picking y-axis values from histogram to plot this graph. So how can I find best fit to this model? Like if the two distributions can be fit to the data How can I compare which one is best? Can I choose Error perr  in the above code to compare?

Comment: For "best" to make sense you need a criterion. We cannot know what you want to find out and hence we cannot know which criterion is "best".

Answer (score 1):

If all data-points need to coincide with the interpolating fit, splines (e.g. [cubic splines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html)) can be used, *generally* resulting in a reasonably smooth fit (only *generally*, because what is "reasonably smooth" depends both on the data and the application).

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import pylab
x_data = np.linspace(0,5,10)
y_data = np.array([5.41041394e-01,1.42611032e-01,3.44975130e-02,
                   7.60221121e-03,1.66115522e-03,3.26808028e-04,
                   6.70741368e-05,1.14168743e-05,5.70843717e-06, 
                   1.42710929e-06])

spline = CubicSpline(x_data, y_data)

plot_x = np.linspace(0,5,1000)
pylab.plot(x_data, y_data, 'b*', label='Data')
pylab.plot(plot_x, spline(plot_x), 'k-', label='Spline')
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

[image: Cubic spline fit]